# Java formatting, how do I get a symbol to stick to an int?

Tags: java, formatting

I'm trying to print out a metric to imperial table and the format needs to be very specific.

Using the format string :

```
System.out.printf("%-2d%-1s|",counter++,"\'");
```

I get the output:
"1 '|"

I need it to be:
"1' |"

**UPDATE:**

I also need it to be left justified, with a total of 4 spaces used, even when the int is 2 digits

Many thanks

Comment: `System.out.printf("%2d%-1s|", 1,"\'");`?

Comment: I also need it to be left justified, with a total of 4 spaces used, even when the int is 2 digits :(

Comment: Please give exact examples of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by converting my int to a String

```
System.out.printf("%-3s|",(Integer.toString(counter++)+"\'"));
```